# Perform a segue in another tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following setup:

1. Tab one: a series of view controller to purchase an item placing it in a shopping cart.
2. Tab two: a series of view controllers that show what you purchased in the past with a button to reorder. When you click reorder it places the items in the shopping cart

This is a simple graphical representation:

[image]

My problem is the following: Given that there are two paths to the shopping cart, it's possible to have two instances of it and that's very confusing to the user. How do I make sure the cart always loads in tab 1?

Comment: You want to say that `SecondViewController` should open in 1st tab in any case, even if user tries to open it in tab 2?

Comment: Yes exactly. So user will change tabs in the background.

Comment: Don't you think it will be a little odd experience for user? Why don't you bring second controller modally on tabviewcontroller, instead of pushing it on navigation controller?

Comment: The designers spent a good deal of time making it look right for the user. Basically the tab is called "order" so it makes sense to be taken to that tab when you click on "reorder" in a previous order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create yours custom segue: subclass `UIStoryboardSegue` and in `-perofrm` implement opening first tab and pushing SecondViewController.

```
- (void) perform
{
    SecondTabViewController* stvc = self.sourceViewController;
    UITabBarController* tbc = stvc.navigationController.tabBarController;
    UINavigationViewController* nvc = tbc.viewControllers.firstObject;
    tbc.selectedViewController = nvc;
    [nvc pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Just spent a couple more hours on this but I am not sure how to implement your suggestion. It's the source navigation controller that pushes the destination controller. If I switch tabs in the middle i will see the new tab but the push will still happen in the old tab. Can you please share some code?

Comment: @Mikael, I don't know full hierarchy of yours viewControllers, so the code is approximate.